# Entity Framework query to custom object Class with List

Tags: entity-framework, linq, model

I am using entity frame work for Web API 2.0 I am trying to query Author Book to a custom Object.

Object is :

```
public class AuthorBooks
{
    public Author Author;
    public List<BookDetail> BookDetails;

    public AuthorBooks() {
        Author = new Author();
        BookDetails = new List<BookDetail>();
    }
}

public class BookDetail
{
    public BookDetail()
    {
        Book = new Book();
        Category = new Category();
        SubCategory = new SubCategory();

    }

    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }


}
```

Here Book, Author, Category and SubCategory are entities

Relation presently working properly is:
Author
----List

```
public class AuthorBooks
{
    public Author Author;
    public List<Book> Book;

    public AuthorBooks() {
        Author = new Author();
        Book = new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

using query I get proper result :

```
AuthorBooks authorBooks = (from a in _context.Authors.Where(author => author.Id == id)
                                   join b in _context.Books on a.Id equals b.AuthorName into b1

                                   select new AuthorBooks { Author = a, Book = b1.ToList()  }).Single<AuthorBooks>();
```

But Now for Above Mentioned Relation : 
  Author
---List

where Book Detail of other Entities related by Id's of Entities Category and SubCategory.

So How Can It be Done with BookDetails Id???

```
 AuthorBooks authorBooks = (from a in _context.Authors.Where(author => author.Id == id)
                                   join b in _context.Books on a.Id equals b.AuthorName into b1
                                   from b2 in b1
                                   join c in _context.Categories on b2.CategoryId equals c.Id
                                   join s in _context.SubCategories on b2.SubCategoryId equals s.Id                                    
                                   select new AuthorBooks { Author = a, BookDetails = #####List<BookDetail>#######  }).Single<AuthorBooks>();
```

Comment: Don't you have navigation properties in your entity classes? If not, may be its good time to add them.

Comment: I do not have navigation Properties as This is an existing Database with older and other things working in it, I am trying to create a Web API 2.0

Comment: Please provide me with a solution, I beg u please :(

Comment: No problem, just it would have been quite easier, of course it's doable with plain LINQ.

Comment: Your solution just worked perfectly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `join` the necessary data needed for `BookDetail` in a subquery and then [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1) the authors query to it to get the desired author - list of detail correlation:

```
AuthorBooks authorBooks = (
    from a in _context.Authors.Where(author => author.Id == id)
    join bd in (from b in _context.Books
                join c in _context.Categories on b.CategoryId equals c.Id
                join s in _context.SubCategories on b.SubCategoryId equals s.Id
                select new BookDetail { Book = b, Category = c, SubCategory = s }
    ) on a.Id equals bd.Book.AuthorName into bookDetails
    select new AuthorBooks { Author = a, BookDetails = bookDetails.ToList() }
).Single();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked just perfectly. I am a nin-come-poop beginner in asp C# and Entityframework.